# How to lock / unlock a gpg hardware token via script

Tags: security, scripting, gpg

I would like to execute `gpg --card-edit; verify; quit` non-interactively to unlock a gpg hardware token (i.e. smartcard or yubikey).

My usecase is:

1. Enter a password e.g. via ssh
2. Store it in the kernel keyring
3. Pass it to the hardware token when needed

One solution that works is `expect` and I've used `autoexpect` to create a script for that but it would contain the user password and is quite clumsy and dependent on the output of a specific gpg version.

`scdaemon` could be an option but I am not sure whether it is a good idea to pass raw commands. I'm afraid to easily brick the token.

Maybe there are tools / scripts that are used for mass personalization of smartcards that could be used?

I'm open to suggestions of what to try next. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While experimenting, I've found a solution using `gpg-connect-agent 'SCD CHECKPIN' /bye`.

By writing a custom pinentry program, I could inject a static key using the Assuan protocol.

I will have to change this pinentry program to read a key from kernel keyring using `keyctl` now.